# Parametric equation to find distance from origin to plane

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation $2x_1 - 3x_2 -6x_3 = -4$ defines a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$

I know the normal vector $\bf a$ for this is $(2,-3,-6)$

I am trying to use the parametric equation of the line that pass through $\bf 0$ with direction vector $\bf a$.

I know how to do this with the projection. I am just using the $\frac{|c|}{||a||}$, which gave me an answer of $\frac{4}{7}$. But I do not know how to get the same answer with parametric equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that line is given by $\langle x,y,z\rangle=\langle2t,-3t,-6t\rangle.$ We know the origin is a point on this line. What we need, then, is to find $t_0$ such that $2(2t_0)-3(-3t_0)-6(-6t_0)=-4$ (why?), then find the distance from the point $\langle2t_0,-3t_0,-6t_0\rangle$ to the origin.

Comment: So, I understand why you are solving for t, You are looking from the origin to the point on the line that intersects with the plane.  and then you apply the distance formula, but when I do this I end up getting 21 instead of 4/7

Comment: I got, $3$ for my $t_o$ value. Why is for $4/7$ not correct, since I am just using the projection equation as stated above

Comment: You should have $t_0=-\frac4{49}.$ Once you use that, you will get the correct answer of $\frac47.$ (It was incorrect for me to say that wasn't right. I made a mistake in my own calculations!)